# Explicit template instantiation vs concept constraints

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, template-instantiation

Let's suppose that I've either a function or a class template that should work only for certains types, e.g. `std::wstring` and `std::string`.

I know that concepts can be used to put a constraint on a template so I would use something like this:

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept StringLike = std::convertible_to<T, std::wstring> || std::convertible_to<T, std::string>;

template<StringLike S>
class A
{
public:
 A(const S& data)
 : data_{data}
{};

private:
 S data_;
}
```

However, I was also thinking about template (class, in this case) instantiation which should achieve the same goal.

```cpp
template<typename S>
class A
{
public:
 A(const S& data)
 : data_{data}
{};

private:
 S data_;
}

template class A<std::string>;
template class A<std::wstring>;
```

If I understood their exchangeability correctly, when should I use one instead of the other?

PS. I know that `std::convertible_to<T, std::string>` is not exactly the same as `template class A<std::string>` since the first is less constrained than the latter but it's just for the sake of the example.

Comment: First, what you are doing is _explicit instantiation_, not _explicit specialization_, and secondly the obvious difference is that the second case can be instantiated with any type (whether or not the explicit instantiations are there; they are not relevant), while it will fail the concept check in the first case. I am not sure how you think these constructs are related. Could you clarify how you think they are interchangeable? What use cases do you have in mind?

Comment: If you want to use specialization to limit instantiation, you need an empty base template declaration - and then only actually define the specialization.

Comment: if they were interchangable then the question would be opinion based. They are not, hence the question hinges on a false premise...

Comment: "since the first is less constrained than the latter but it's just for the sake of the example." but then what is the example for? It is not for two variants that are equivalent. Perhaps explaining the use case would help to clarify the question

Comment: @user17732522 Yeah, I'm sorry I intended *explicit instantiation* (I'll modify soon the post where possible). 

The problem comes into my mind when I was trying to achieve the following: "I want a template class (or function) that works only for specific types and gives a compilation error when instantiated with "unknown" types, e.g. an `int`". I first wrote my code using concepts but then I found the existence of template instantiation that seems a way to achieve the same goal.

Comment: @ncx But explicit instantiations don't achieve that. You can still use e.g. `A<int>` with the example you are showing. It is not clear to me where you see the connection.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number well, I made a question since they seems to me ambiguous, I'm glad that they are not interchangable then. :) Can you explain me in which case I should use one instead of the other?

Comment: @user17732522 Ok, so my premise is wrong, ouch! What is the problem that template instantiation tries to solve, then?

Comment: @ncx It is mainly used to reduce compilation time and source file dependencies by avoiding that template specializations need to be implicitly instantiated in multiple translation units, but that doesn't work in the way you are showing. You would need to place the instantiations into a single `.cpp` file and then add explicit instantiation declarations (prefixed with `extern`) to the header.

Comment: @user17732522 Ok -to summarize- so I can have concepts to inject my restricitive logic e.g., restrict which types can be used to instantiate class `A` but then I can also improve the compilation time performances by using explcit template instantiation, using the following structure:
- `.hpp` contains the aforementioned declaration of `A` with the concept and the `extern` explicit instantiation declarations that I know for sure that will be used in my program;
- `.tpp` contains the `A` definitions, if any;
- `.cpp` contains all the explicit template instantiations of `A`.

Is it correct?

Comment: imho you should rephrase the question. Perhaps something along the line of "I think those two are more or less equivalent, because ..... Why are they not equivalent?". Then some one can write a proper answer.

Comment: @user7854092 More or less, yes, but stick with the normal approach defining all members in the header unless you really have a need to use this explicit instantiation approach. It comes with its own problems. (And as we established it is orthogonal to the use of concept constraints.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two things here and they are not interchangeable.

Concepts are used to constrain template arguments. This is what you should use if you want to restrict the type arguments your `A` class should be instantiated with.

Explicit template instantiation, that you show in the second example, is something different. Remember that templates are not classes or functions but *blueprints* from which the compiler generates code (with a particular set of template arguments). Typically, this would happen when the compiler encounters the use of a template in your code (in each translation unit). This is called *implicit template instantiation*. However, you can also tell the compiler to instantiate a template from a set of arguments. This is called *explicit template instantiation*. This is what you did here:

```
template class A<std::string>;
template class A<std::wstring>;
```

With your example, this would make no difference, you could still instantiate `A<int>`. Example:

```
#include <string>

template<typename S>
class A
{
public:
 A(const S& data)
 : data_{data}
{};

private:
 S data_;
};

template class A<std::string>;
template class A<std::wstring>;

int main()
{
    A<std::string> a1("42");
    A<std::wstring> a2(L"42");
    A<int> a(42);
}
```

However, let's say you have this:

`A.h`

```
#pragma once

template<typename S>
class A
{
public:
   A(const S& data);

private:
   S data_;
};
```

`A.cpp`

```
#include "A.h"
#include <string>

template <typename S>
A<S>::A(const S& data) : data_{data}
{}

template class A<std::string>;
template class A<std::wstring>;
```

and finally:
`main.cpp`

```
#include "A.h"
#include <string>

int main()
{
    A<std::string> a1("42");
    A<std::wstring> a2(L"42");
    A<int> a(42); // error
}
```

Since the definition of `A`'s constructor is in another translation unit (`A.cpp`), you cannot use it in `main.cpp`. However, you explicitly instantiated `A` for `std::string` and `std::wstring` and that makes them available outside that translation unit.

Explicit template instantiation has two forms:

- explicit instantiation declaration: this is used to suppress an implicit instantiation. Such a declaration is introduced with the `extern` keyword. This tells the compiler that the definition is found in another translation unit (or later in the same translation unit). The purpose is to reduce compilation time by generating a single instantiation in a single translation unit. See https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/cpp11-language-templates#extern-templates.
- explicit instantiation definition: forces the instantiation of the type it refers to. This must occur is the namespace of the template.

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth explanation, very appreciated. Considering the explicit template instantiation declarations, can I put those inside the header file - after the template declaration - and insert their correspondent explicit template instantiation definitions in the associated source file instead of spreading the extern stuff in all headers that use them? Is this considered a good practice?